# Advice on my opacity slider (Pure CSS, No JS)

Tags: html, css, slider, opacity

I have created this pen for an opacity slider that I want to use for client testimonials. I based the CSS of the testimonials off another pen which I could link here if someone would like it. I am very new to coding and am an extreme beginner so pardon my silly mistakes. :P Does anyone have any advice on how to improve this design and how to make it more versatile for once I add more testimonials (maybe 6-8). I am sort of confused by the animation properties and how they are working, i.e the delay and the animation duration. I just kept playing with the numbers until it worked. I plan to have this "slider" in the footer of my site. One thing that bugs me is that it is not centered. How could I center the slider? Also what should I do about the height of the "slider"? The way I am currently doing it doesn't really make sense. Kind of like a lot of that code.

Thanks so so much for any advice given, I strongly appreciate it. :)

Here is the link to my Codepen: [link] (http://codepen.io/ericshio/pen/grzboq)

HTML:

```
<div class="test-slider">
<div class="test-slide">
<figure class="test">
<img class="img-circle img-border" src="http://www.themainconcept.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/eric.png" width="40%"/>
<h2>Eric S.</h2>
<h4>Some Guy</h4>
<blockquote>Insert cheesy quote here! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, at lorem graecis ius, qui at veri vocent.</blockquote>

</figure>
</div>
<div class="test-slide">
    <figure class="test">
<img class="img-circle img-border" src="http://i1.wp.com/www.visualelegance.ca/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/danielliasquare.png?zoom=2&amp;w=1020" />
<h2>Daniel &amp; Lia</h2>
<h4>Couple</h4>
<blockquote>Words go here from what people have to say.</blockquote>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.test-slider {
    width: 25em;
    height: 25em;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.test-slide {
    position: absolute;
    animation: 30s slider infinite;
    -webkit-animation: 30s test-slider infinite;
    opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes test-slider {
    10% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

div.test-slide:nth-child(0) {
    animation-delay: 0s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
}

div.test-slide:nth-child(1) {
    animation-delay: 15s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 15s;
}

figure.test {
    font-family: lato !important;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10% 1%;
    min-width: 15em;
    max-width: 20em;
    width: 100%;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1em;
    background-color: #2d2d2d;
    padding: 8% 8% 8% 8%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(-25deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 100%);
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 0.3em 0.3em 0.3em 0.3em;
}

figure.test img {
    width: 50%;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}

figure.test h2, figure.test h4 {
    font-family: lato;
    text-transform: none;
    margin: 0;
}

figure.test h2 {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
}

figure.test h4 {
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #a6a6a6;
}

figure.test blockquote {
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 8%;
    opacity: 1;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 1em;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 0.3em 0.3em 0.3em 0.3em;
    box-shadow: inset -0.1em -0.1em 0.2em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
}

.img-border {
    border: 0.5em solid tan;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -ms-border-radius: 50%;
    -o-border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0.4em 0.4em 2em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.img-circle {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -ms-border-radius: 50%;
    -o-border-radius: 50%;
}

blockquote, blockquote:before, blockquote:after, blockquote::before, blockquote::after {
    margin: auto;
    border: none;
    position: initial;
    content: " ";
    quotes: "\201C""\201D""\2018""\2019";
}

blockquote {
}

blockquote:before {
    content: open-quote;
}

blockquote::before, blockquote::after {
    display: inline;
}

blockquote:after {
    content: close-quote;
}
```

JS:

```
NONE >:)
```

Comment: I don't see any slide in the pen.

Comment: Sorry it is not a slide, it just switches. I did not know what to call it. It works like a slider but instead it fades in and out with the different images basically. Instead of sliding in, it just fades in and out. It's an "opacity-er".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's more important than just to give you the solution is to help you actually see that your element in fact **is centered**.

I like using red when I debug CSS code, so try putting:

```
.test-slider {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

---

Now, you probably see for yourself that **`.test-slider`** is indeed centered, but its child,**`.test-slide`**, is anchored on the top left corner of its parent and since the parent is larger in width, it therefore seems to be off.

To fix that, just set:

```
.test-slider {
    width: 20.4em; /* Instead of 25em */
}
```

Since **`.test-slider`** is invisible and just serves to wrap **`.test-slide`**, you don't really care about its width, so this solution is fine.

Another way to do it is by setting:

```
.test-slide {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

---

Since you use **`position: absolute`** on **`.test-slide`** instead of **`position: relative`**, you will not face any problems. If later you want to change it to **`position: relative`**, you can just set:

```
.test-slide {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Or you could even better set:

```
.test-slider { /* The parent */
    text-align: center;
}
```

---

Check out the following fiddles for a more visual representation:

- With the first solution → [here](https://jsfiddle.net/o1greeLe/).
- With the second solution → [here](https://jsfiddle.net/o1greeLe/1/).

**Snippet:**

```css
.test-slider {
 width: 20.4em;
 height: 30em;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.test-slide {
 position: absolute;
 animation: 30s slider infinite;
 -webkit-animation: 30s test-slider infinite;
 opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes test-slider {
 10% {
  opacity: 1;
 }
 50% {
  opacity: 0;
 }
}

div.test-slide:nth-child(0) {
 animation-delay: 0s;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
}

div.test-slide:nth-child(1) {
 animation-delay: 15s;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 15s;
}

figure.test {
 font-family: lato !important;
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: 10% 1%;
 min-width: 15em;
 max-width: 20em;
 width: 100%;
 color: #000000;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 1em;
 background-color: #2d2d2d;
 padding: 8% 8% 8% 8%;
 background-image: linear-gradient(-25deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 100%);
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border-radius: 0.3em 0.3em 0.3em 0.3em;
}

figure.test img {
 width: 50%;
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-bottom: 2%;
}

figure.test h2, figure.test h4 {
 font-family: lato;
 text-transform: none;
 margin: 0;
}

figure.test h2 {
 font-weight: bold;
 color: white;
}

figure.test h4 {
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #a6a6a6;
}

figure.test blockquote {
 margin-top: 5%;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 padding: 8%;
 opacity: 1;
 font-style: italic;
 font-size: 1em;
 background-color: white;
 border-radius: 0.3em 0.3em 0.3em 0.3em;
 box-shadow: inset -0.1em -0.1em 0.2em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
 text-align: left;
 position: relative;
}

.img-border {
 border: 0.5em solid tan;
 border-radius: 50%;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 -ms-border-radius: 50%;
 -o-border-radius: 50%;
 box-shadow: 0.4em 0.4em 2em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.img-circle {
 margin: auto;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 border-radius: 50%;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 -ms-border-radius: 50%;
 -o-border-radius: 50%;
}

blockquote, blockquote:before, blockquote:after, blockquote::before, blockquote::after {
  margin: auto;
 border: none;
 position: initial;
 content: " ";
 quotes: "\201C""\201D""\2018""\2019";
}

blockquote:before {
 content: open-quote;
}

blockquote::before, blockquote::after {
 display: inline;
}

blockquote:after {
 content: close-quote;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-slider">
  <div class="test-slide">
    <figure class="test">
      <img class="img-circle img-border" src="http://www.themainconcept.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/eric.png" width="40%" />
      <h2>Eric S.</h2>
      <h4>Some Guy</h4>
      <blockquote>Insert cheesy quote here! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, at lorem graecis ius, qui at veri vocent.</blockquote>

    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="test-slide">
    <figure class="test">
      <img class="img-circle img-border" src="http://i1.wp.com/www.visualelegance.ca/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/danielliasquare.png?zoom=2&amp;w=1020" />
      <h2>Daniel &amp; Lia</h2>
      <h4>Couple</h4>
      <blockquote>Words go here from what people have to say.</blockquote>
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Amazing. I had a red border while I was making it, but I deleted it for presentation purposes lol. Thanks so much for all the brilliant help! :) Cheers!!!

Comment: What would you recommend for the animation for when I add more testimonials? How does the animation, delay, and keyframes work together? I just played with those numbers to get them to kinda of work, however I'd prefer if the fade out wasn't so long. I am still a bit confused on how the whole animation thing is working. Thanks!

Comment: I like everything except, as you you correctly said, the fade-out. It's just so long and time-wasting that nobody would actually willingly pay attention. I believe cutting the fade-out duration to half would make for a great overall animation.

Comment: Exactly, I am thinking the same thing. Do you know how I could fix that? I am not to sure how my animation works, like I said I just played with the values.

Comment: Cut down that **`30s`** you have when you call the animation to something less and also try putting in the animation: **`0% {opacity: 1} 100%{opacity: 0}`**.

Comment: I actually added 5 testimonials and now it looks alot better. I actually decided to do some math and so now I fully understand how it works. I made each slide 20s long and in total the animation is 100s. There is a 5% fade in and 5% fade out. Then the next slide happens. Check it out. :) Thanks for the suggestions!